# How to give rest to mysql cpu while process 100000 queriesne by one in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-queue

I am using laravel jobs to do calculation on week end during calculation i need to run almost 100000 queries in a row one by one due to this my mysql server usage reaches 100% i am thinking of to give rest between this process .How i can do this?

Here is the function which i am calling about 25000 times inside loop which has almost 30 queries.

```
public function calculateConsignmentOneByOne($consignment, $total_consignments, $current_iteration, $user_id, $notify)
{

    if ($consignment->finalize == 0) {

        $type = 'Income';
        $customer = $consignment->customers;
        $delivery_run_id = $consignment->delivery_run_id;
        if ($consignment->consignment_type == 'pickup' || $consignment->consignment_type == 'return') {
            $delivery_address_id = $consignment->pickup_address;
        } else {
            $delivery_address_id = $consignment->delivery_address;
        }
        $customer_id = $consignment->customer_id;
        $rate_zone = $consignment->rate_zone_id;
        if ($rate_zone == null) {
            $address_to_rate_zone_mapping = getRateZoneByAddressMapping($consignment, $type);

            if ($address_to_rate_zone_mapping != false) {
                $rate_zone = 0;
                $rate_zone = $address_to_rate_zone_mapping;
            } else {
                $rate_zone =   $this->getRateZone($delivery_run_id, $delivery_address_id, $type);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($consignment->invoice)) {
            if ($consignment->invoice->status === 3) {
                $error = 'Related Invoice is Approved,Now you Can not modify charges';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invoice_approved', $error, $type);
            }
        }
        $productType = $consignment->product_type_id;
        if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_run') {
            $error = 'No Delivery Run is Assigned to this consignment';
            chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_run', $error, $type);
        } else if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_zone') {
            if ($consignment->consignment_type == 'pickup' || $consignment->consignment_type == 'return') {
                $address_msg = 'Pickup address';
            } else {
                $address_msg = 'Delivery address';
            }
            $error = 'Delivery Zone not found with current suburb and postcode given in ' . $address_msg;

            chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_zone', $error, $type);
        } else if (empty($productType)) {
            $error = 'Please Attach Product Type to Consignment';
            chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'product_type_error', $error, $type);
        } else if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_address') {
            $error = 'Delivery Address not Found , May be Deleted';
            chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_address', $error, $type);
        } else {
            $rate_charge = $this->getRateChargeByRateZoneAndCustomer($rate_zone, $type, $consignment, $customer);

            if ($rate_charge === 'rate_not_found') {
                $error = 'Rate Card in Customer Charge with "' . RateZone::find($rate_zone)->name . '" Rate zone or Charge Type not found';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'rate_not_found', $error, $type);
            }
            if ($rate_charge === 'customer_not_found') {
                $error = 'Customer Not Found, May be Deleted';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'customer_not_found', $error, $type);
            }
            if ($rate_charge === "invalid_carton_pallet") {
                $error = 'No pallets or cartons given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_carton_pallet', $error, $type);
            }
            if ($rate_charge === "invalid_invoice_value") {
                $error = 'No invoice value given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_invoice_value', $error, $type);
            }
            if ($rate_charge === "invalid_weight") {
                $error = 'No Weight value given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_weight', $error, $type);
            } else {


                if ($type == 'Income') {
                    $rate_charge_array =   array('class' => null, 'type' => $type, 'description' => $this->chargeDescription, 'income' => $rate_charge, 'expense' => 0.00, 'rate_zone_id' => $rate_zone, 'customer_id' => $customer->id, 'apply_fuel_levy' => $this->fuelLevy, 'object_id' => $consignment->id, 'model' => 'Consignment', 'automatic' => 1);
                } else {
                    $rate_charge_array = array('class' => null, 'type' => $type, 'description' => $this->chargeDescription, 'income' => 0.00, 'expense' => $rate_charge, 'rate_zone_id' => $rate_zone, 'customer_id' => $customer->id, 'apply_fuel_levy' => $this->fuelLevy, 'object_id' => $consignment->id, 'model' => 'Consignment', 'automatic' => 1);
                }
                if ($type == 'Income') {
                    $final_charges = $this->getAdhocChargeRate($consignment, 'Consignment');
                }

                $final_charges[] = $rate_charge_array;
                $final_charges = collect($final_charges);

                Charge::where('object_id', $consignment->id)->where('automatic', 1)->where('model', 'Consignment')->delete();
                ChargeError::where('object_id', $consignment->id)->where('model', 'Consignment')->delete();

                $this->storeAutoCalculatedConsignmentCharges($final_charges);
                $this->calculateFuelLevyForConsignment($consignment->id);



                //this will keep updating fuel levy with each consignment calculation
                // if (InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->exists()) {
                //     $income = 0;
                //     $expense = 0;
                //     $total = InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->first();
                //     $income = (float)$total->income + (float)$consignment->charges()->sum('fuel_levy_value');
                //     $expense += 0;
                //     InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->update(['income' => $income, 'expense' => $expense]);
                //     $invoice = Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id);


                //     Invoice::where('id', $consignment->invoice_id)->update(['income' => $invoice->invoice_totals()->sum('income'), 'expense' => $invoice->invoice_totals()->sum('expense')]);
                // }
                Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 0]);
            }
        }



        $last_consignment = Consignment::select('id', 'invoice_id')->where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('finalize', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $invoice_id = $consignment->invoice_id;

        //if its last consignment to calculate and notify is true
        if ($notify && $total_consignments == $current_iteration) {
            Notification_Helper::sendNotification($user_id, 'Invoice Calculation is Completed ', route('invoices.show', $consignment->invoice_id));
        }
        $upload_to_xero = 0;
        if (XeroCustomer::where('customer_id', $consignment->customer_id)->exists()) {
            if (XeroCustomer::where('customer_id', $consignment->customer_id)->first()->automatic_invoice_upload_xero == 1) {
                $upload_to_xero = 1;
            }
        }

        if ($consignment->id == $last_consignment->id) {
            Invoice::find($invoice_id)->update(['calculation_complete' => 1]);
            $this->consignmentSumup($invoice_id);
        }


        //if its last consignment to calculate and has no charge error then
        //invoice will be uploaded to xero
        if ($consignment->id == $last_consignment->id) {
            //checking if error exists Related to current invoice
            $consignment_charge_exists = ChargeError::where('model', 'Consignment')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from(with(new Consignment)->getTable())
                    ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
            })->exists();

            $po_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Purchase Order')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from(with(new PurchaseOrder)->getTable())
                    ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
            })->exists();

            $so_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Sale Order')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from(with(new SaleOrder)->getTable())
                    ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
            })->exists();

            $sp_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Storage Period')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from(with(new StoragePeriod)->getTable())
                    ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
            })->exists();
            if (!$consignment_charge_exists && !$po_charge_exist && !$so_charge_exist && !$sp_charge_exist && $upload_to_xero == 1 && $this->consignmentSumup($invoice_id)) {
                UploadInvoiceToXero::dispatch($consignment->invoice_id)->onQueue('invoice')->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2));
                // CustomerController::uploadAutoInvoiceToXero($consignment->invoice_id, $xeroCredential, new CustomerSettingService);
                Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1]);
            } else {
                Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1, 'charge_error' => 1]);
            }
        } else {
            Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1, 'charge_error' => 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have 100000 queries at all,. revise your program and see if you can limit the amount massivly

Comment: Because i am doing calculation on for customer invoices which is present in table . for that i need to get data from database perform calcualtion on them and then again save it into database fro each customer, there are 500 customers and each customer will have atleast 500 data . can you propose good solution here?

Comment: you did describe it in the text, but as every connection is one thread only they run sequentially. Even when you do i, so that it runs multiple threads, you must learn about multithreading and locks. you could chekc if the 30 queires ccan not be joind to 1 or 2 , further you should chelk if you can't run the queres for all customers at once.

Comment: Can you please share reference from where i can learn this?

Comment: multipthreading in php can be searched by searcheingime, the restructering and optimizing is a matter of experience, there are no tuturiqals as the depending on goal you have to revise database and programming. here youi can enabkle general log and see what is happening in  your databse and what time every thing takes. from here you triy to optimize